# Job quits unexpectedly

Tags: powershell, concurrency, start-job

I would like to use `Start-Job` to simultaneously monitor (tail) more than one log file using `Get-Content file -Wait -Last 1` (`-Last 1` to avoid opening the whole log).

Running `gc $file -Last 1 -Wait` allows to tail only one file.
Wrapping that up in a `Start-Job -Scriptblock` quits the job immediately.

I had something like this in mind.

```
Start-Job -Name srv1 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\srv1\$log" -Wait -Last 1} | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\autogrep.log}
Start-Job -Name srv2 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\srv2\$log" -Wait -Last 1} | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\autogrep.log}
Start-Job -Name srv3 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\srv3\$log" -Wait -Last 1} | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\autogrep.log}
Start-Job -Name srv4 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\srv4\$log" -Wait -Last 1} | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\autogrep.log}
Start-Job -Name srv5 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\srv5\$log" -Wait -Last 1} | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\autogrep.log}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simultaneously writing to the same output file from different jobs is going to create a race condition unless you have a scheduler in place to coordinate write access. Also, if you want to read a log from an UNC path you need to provide the path as `\\server\share\file`.

Try something like this:

```
$servers = 'srv1', 'srv2', 'srv3', 'srv4', 'srv5'
$jobs    = @()

$servers | ForEach-Object {
  $jobs += Start-Job -Name $_ -ScriptBlock {
    Param($server, $log)
    Get-Content "\\$server\share\$log" -Wait -Last 1
  } -ArgumentList $_, 'your.log'
}

while ($jobs.State -contains 'Running') {
  $jobs | Where-Object { $_.hasMoreData } |
    Receive-Job |
    Select-String 'matching some text only' |
    Out-File 'D:\autogrep.log' -Append
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

Note that if you're still using PowerShell v2 you need to replace `$jobs.State` with `@($jobs | Select-Object -Expand State)`, because PowerShell doesn't automatically unroll arrays on property access prior to v3.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the single output file reference. Calling `Start-Job` manually for each server and log desired now works as expected. However, when I try to wrap inside a for loop replacing the server name the jobs do not start as expected.


`foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Start-Job -Name $server -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\$server\logfile" -Wait -Last 1 | Select-String "matching some text only" | Out-File D:\$server.log}
}`

I'm on Win7/5.0 RTM

Comment: To be able to use variables from the rest of  your script inside a scriptblock you need to either pass them as arguments (like in my code sample) or use the `using:` [scope modifier](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).